# HighCharts Custom maps not working on react

Tags: highcharts

I am building a web app on React Js and trying too build a custom map of floors of building. I followed the article on https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/create-custom-maps and created an application using HTML CSS and JavaScript,https://jsfiddle.net/hop9cqxj/92/ however I want it inside of ReactJS. Whenever I paste the map options into the React JS variable. I get the error below:

Error
Highcharts error #17: [www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=map](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/17/?missingModuleFor=map)

The demo work's link is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-sunset-o3pf92

- missingModuleFor: map

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Highmaps` source code and `mapChart` chart constructor type.

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highmaps";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import React from "react";

const option2 = {...};

export default function DeltaSecond() {
  return (
    <>
      <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={option2}
        constructorType="mapChart"
      ></HighchartsReact>
    </>
  );
}
```

Also, I have noticed that Highcharts doesn't work in `StrictMode` from the newest React, so you can report a potential bug on `highcharts-react` github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-satoshi-xxt-xxtkp9?file=/src/components/buildings/Delta/delta2nd.js

**Docs:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official#options-details

Comment: Thank you, sir, for the help. I am able to do it.

Comment: can you look into this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73740601/how-to-trigger-onhover-function-in-highcarts-tooltip